# Should I respond to recruiter if I don't have the skill sets/experience years required

Tags: software-industry, recruitment

I received many emails from tech recruiters, meanwhile I'm actively looking for a job to start my career as a software developer.

Is it effective to respond to their emails regarding jobs that I'm not qualified for (or the ones that I'm not interested) and ask if they have vacancies that fit my skill sets?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding jobs you are not qualified:

Yes, you should apply. Usually in a job description there would be a lot of requirement but it doesn't mean that if you don't have all this skills they won't hire you. 
IMO a good rule is : if you have 60% (or more) of the skills you should apply.

Regarding jobs you are not interested:

Why are you not interested? Because of the skills required? The level of the position? Because the company is too big( or too small)?

I suggest to apply to every jobs that seems in your reach. A job description is not everything, meeting the people you will work with ( especially your boss that if your are young can become a mentor) is also very important.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not interested In some of the jobs because of their locations and/or the job responsibilities show that they use some technologies that are clearly outdated.

Comment: I might go higher that 60%, but still this is a great answer.  In general a company will put our the requirements for a PERFECT candidate knowing they will have to settle in most cases.

Comment: When I was younger, I heard 80%, and more recently 70%. But it's still a good rule of thumb. If you think you're able to meet the bulk of the job requirements, you should definitely apply.